# Grouping row on plage of date on Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this:

| Quantity | Usage date |
| --- | --- |
| 75 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 75 | 2023-04-02 00:00:00.000 |
| 75 | 2023-04-03 00:00:00.000 |
| 76 | 2023-04-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 76 | 2023-04-05 00:00:00.000 |
| 75 | 2023-04-06 00:00:00.000 |
| 75 | 2023-04-07 00:00:00.000 |
| 75 | 2023-04-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 75 | 2023-04-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 74 | 2023-04-10 00:00:00.000 |
| 74 | 2023-04-11 00:00:00.000 |

I need using sql to transforme it on something like:

| RN | Quantity | Usage date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 75 | 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 75 | 2023-04-02 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 75 | 2023-04-03 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 76 | 2023-04-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 76 | 2023-04-05 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 75 | 2023-04-06 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 75 | 2023-04-07 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 75 | 2023-04-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 75 | 2023-04-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 74 | 2023-04-10 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 74 | 2023-04-11 00:00:00.000 |

I try using window functions:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Quantity" ORDER BY "Usage date") AS RN, "Quantity", "Usage date"
FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY "Usage date";
```

but I didn't get the result I wanted

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you show us what you have tried so far and what was the result. (Please have look at [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 1):

You want a rank that increments everytime the quantity changes. In Snowflake, we can use [CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional_change_event) for this:

```
select t.*,
    1 + conditional_change_event(quantity) over(order by usage_date) rn
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, using window functions `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()`

You have a `gaps and islands` problem, you could use the difference between two row_numbers to give a unique id to each successive group of rows.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Usage_date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Quantity ORDER BY Usage_date) AS GRP,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Usage_date) AS RN
  FROM your_table_name
),
CTE2 AS (
  SELECT min(RN) OVER (PARTITION BY GRP) as m_no, Quantity, Usage_date, GRP
  FROM CTE
  ORDER BY Usage_date
)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY m_no) as RN, Quantity, Usage_date
FROM CTE2;
```